# Follow on Twitter using MGTwitterEngine iphone

Tags: iphone, twitter, mgtwitterengine, social-media

I am using MGTwitterEngine for integrate Twitter on my iPhone application. so i want to follow a particular person using this library. can any one suggest me how i do this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you got solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not try to follow a user ..

Let try this metthod

```
-(NSString *)enableUpdatesFor:(NSString *)username
```

and let me know

Comment: Hi Amit, when m calling this method m getting following error...

Request F8F5F289-D9F0-45FF-9DDB-E20E66311612 failed with error: Error Domain=HTTP Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 401.)"

Any help please...